# Core Data Predicate: all Groups with Activity on an NSDate?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsdate, fetch

I have the following data model:

```
Group(name, color, activities*) // one group may have many activities
Activity(startTime, endTime, location, Group*) // startTime and endTime are NSDate, group is an inverse relationship
```

so if I want to get all Groups who have at least one activity which on on a specified NSDate, say theTime, what predicate should I construct?

My thoughts:

1. first get all activities
2. then put their groups into a Set in order to remove duplicate Groups
3. convert the Set to an array

so:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ >= startTime AND %@ <= endTime", theTime]
```

fetch an array of Activities then:

```
for (Activity *activity in activities)
{
    [theSet add:activity.group];
}
```

so I got an array of unique Groups that have at least one activity on theTime?

Is there any other way to just do a fetch without post-processing?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Can I do:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ >= activities.startTime AND %@ <= activities.endTime", theTime]
```

???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well your question, yes.

You can do it fecthing against `Group` instead of `Activity` entity. In this manner you can avoid to fetch first `Activity`ies enitity and then apply a filter. Since `activities` is not a scalar value, you need a predicate modifier (`ANY`, `ALL`, etc.) or a SUBQUERY.

About your question I would do the following:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(activities, $x, $x.startTime >= %@ and $x.endTime <= %@).@count > 0)", theStartTime, theEndTime];
```

About the predicate, I suppose yuo want to find `Group`s that contain `Activity`ies included in a specificified range.

Try and let me know. Hope that helps.